# zeromq ROUTER connect to ROUTER ,losing the first message

Tags: zeromq, router

my env: python 2.7 , pyzmq-13.1.0-py2.7-win32, windows 7 sp1 x64

- 2 ZMQ_ROUTER sockets, A and B;
- A binds to an address and is assigned an identity;
- B is assigned an identity and connects to A;
- B sends message to A, then the first message is always lost

But there's no any question under C# code ,what's wrong with it?

the python code :

```
    import time
    import struct
    import zmq
    import threading

    def relay(contextBind):
        backend = contextBind.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
        identity = '2'
        backend.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, identity )
        backend.bind('tcp://*:5678')

        poller = zmq.Poller()
        poller.register(backend, zmq.POLLIN)
        while True:
            try:
                sockets = dict(poller.poll())
            except Exception,ex:
                print ex
                break  

            if backend in sockets:
                if sockets[backend] == zmq.POLLIN:
                    msg = backend.recv_multipart()
                    print msg

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        #the first message is lost
        context = zmq.Context()
        relayThread = threading.Thread(target=relay, args=(context,))
        relayThread.start()

        frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
        identity = '3'
        frontend.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, identity )

        try:
            frontend.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5678')
        except zmq.error.ZMQError, ex:
            print ex

        i = 1
        while True:
            print 'send ', str(i),'\n'
            frontend.send('2', zmq.SNDMORE)
            frontend.send(str(i) + ' msg')
            i = i + 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: it's solved by added a statement 'time.sleep(1)' before 'i=1'.

Comment: I have the same issue, and your solution solved my issue. Is it a bug of ZMQ?

Comment: @user2100910 please refer to zmq slow join behavior.